# how to properly use toHaveBeenCalled() for unit testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, constructor, jasmine

I need to write a test that sets *state* then test to see if *stateManagerService* has been called. I'm getting the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'vm.stateManagerService.go')

main.controller.js

```
export class MainController {
    constructor($state, stateManagerService) {
        'ngInject';
        this.$state = $state; 
        if($state.current.name === 'main') {
            stateManagerService.go('list');
        }
    }

}
```

unit test main.controller.spec.js

```
describe('controllers', () => {
    let vm;

    //
    beforeEach(inject(($controller, $state, stateManagerService) => {
        vm = $controller('MainController');

    }));

    it('should call stateManagerService when current name is main', ()=> {
        vm.$state.current.name = 'main'
        console.log(vm.$state.current.name)
        expect(vm.stateManagerService.go()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Also (slightly off-topic) I'm still confused as to why *this.$state = $state* is required. If left out, I get an error saying $state is undefined.

Update: Now getting the errors

> Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for go() (line 1887)
>
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'vm.stateManagerService.go')

stateManager.service.js

```
export class StateManagerService {
    constructor($state, $stateParams, platformDetectService){
        'ngInject';
        //deps
        this.$state = $state;
        this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        this.isMobile = platformDetectService.isMobile;

        //internal
        this.lastStateName = null;
        this.lastStateParams = null;
    }

    //storage method for current state
    go (stateName, params){
        this.lastStateParams = this.$stateParams.page;
        this.lastState = this.$state.current.name.split('.')[1];



        let nextState = (this.isMobile) ? 'mobile.' + stateName : 'map.' + stateName;

        this.$state.go(nextState, params)
    }

    //returns last state or list
    goBack (){
        let lastState = this.lastState || 'list',
            page = this.lastStateParams || null;

        this.go(lastState, {page})
    }

}
```

Comment: Dont forget to spy on your `vm.stateManagerService.go` by `spyOn(vm.stateManagerService, 'go')`

Comment: Jasmine documentation for **spies** and `.toHaveBeenCalled` - http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies without method explicity invocation

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify on the function pointer, not the return value of the function.

It should have been

```
expect(vm.stateManagerService.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Note the absence of `()` around the `go`